# Calculate days between 2 datetime columns in dask dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dataframe, dask

I have a dask dataframe that contains two columns, which is string format, like this

```
start_date  end_date
2018-09-01  2018-10-01
2018-09-02  2018-09-22
...
```

I would like to calculate the number of days between the two columns. If it is a pandas dataframe, I can do:

```
df["num_days"] = (df["end_day"]-df["start_date"]).apply(lambda s:s.total_seconds()/24/60/60)
```

But in dask dataframe, that does not seems to work. Anyways to calculate elapsed days between to columns in this case?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`dask.dataframe`](http://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe.html) supports a useful subset of the Pandas API, including [`Series.dt`](http://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe-api.html#dask.dataframe.Series.dt) methods. Therefore, you can use this functionality directly:

```
import dask.dataframe as dd

df = dd.read_csv(r'file.csv', delim_whitespace=True,
                 parse_dates=['start_date', 'end_date'])

df['days'] = (df['end_date'] - df['start_date']).dt.days

print(df.compute())

  start_date   end_date  days
0 2018-09-01 2018-10-01    30
1 2018-09-02 2018-09-22    20
```